# How can i calculate the total from an sqflite database with a for loop and print it out with a future builder

Tags: for-loop, arraylist, flutter, dart

i am new to dart and flutter and i'm writing a method within it is a for loop to add data gotten from an sqflite database but the data returned is null always, please can anyone help me correct the code;

The declarations and i called the method in an initstate

```
Future<int> mainTotal;
  int total = 0;
  int multiple;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedItems = [];
    super.initState();
    calculateTotal();
  }
```

This is the function that returns future int

```
void calculateTotal() async {
    final dao = Provider.of<ItemListDao>(context);
    List<ItemList> itemLists = await dao.getAllItemLists(widget.checkListId);

    for (int i = 0; i < itemLists.length; i++) {
      int noOfItems = itemLists[i].noOfItems as int;
      int unitPrice = itemLists[i].unitPrice as int;
      multiple = noOfItems * unitPrice;
      total += multiple;
    }

    mainTotal = total as Future<int>;
  }
```

Tried to use a future builder to get the data

```
Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: mainTotal, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Text('Awaiting result...');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  return Text('Total: ${snapshot.data}');
              }
              return null; // unreachable
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

On the initState() you need to return the future and assign it to the mainTotal variable, like this:

```
mainTotal = calculateTotal();
```

Otherwise, the variable will be null, and when you put the value later on the variable the FutureBuilder won't realize.

Here is an example similar to your code to understand the problem:

```
Future<int> mainTotal;
int total = 0;
int multiple;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  print("before calculateTotal() mainTotal: $mainTotal");
  mainTotal = calculateTotal();
  print("after calculateTotal() mainTotal: $mainTotal");
}

Future<int> calculateTotal() async {
  print("calculateTotal() starting...");
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  List<List<int>> itemLists = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 4]
  ];

  for (int i = 0; i < itemLists.length; i++) {
    int noOfItems = itemLists[i].length;
    int unitPrice = itemLists[i].length;
    multiple = noOfItems * unitPrice;
    total += multiple;
  }

  print("calculateTotal() finished");
  return total;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {});
      },
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: mainTotal, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              print("connectionState: none");
              return Text('Awaiting result...');
            case ConnectionState.active:
              print("connectionState: active");
              return Text('Awaiting result...');
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              print("connectionState: waiting");
              return Text('Awaiting result...');
            case ConnectionState.done:
              print("connectionState: done");
              if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              return Text('Total: ${snapshot.data}');
          }
          return null; // unreachable
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And this is the output of the prints:

```
I/flutter (30319): before calculateTotal() mainTotal: null
I/flutter (30319): calculateTotal() starting...
I/flutter (30319): after calculateTotal() mainTotal: Instance of 'Future<int>'
I/flutter (30319): connectionState: waiting
I/flutter (30319): calculateTotal() finished
I/flutter (30319): connectionState: done
```

If you don't return the variable and you assign it later, this would be the output:

```
I/flutter (30799): before calculateTotal() mainTotal: null
I/flutter (30799): calculateTotal() starting...
I/flutter (30799): after calculateTotal() mainTotal: null
I/flutter (30799): connectionState: none
I/flutter (30799): calculateTotal() finished
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you seeing 'Awaiting result...' or 'Total: null'?

Comment: Awaiting Result

Comment: The problem seems to be in the dao.getAllItemLists() method, could you post that implementation?

Answer (score 0):

So i reconstructed my logic and this worked for me.

```
Widget _printTotal() {
final dao = Provider.of<ItemListDao>(context);
return FutureBuilder(
  future: dao.getAllItemLists(
      widget.checkListId), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    List<ItemList> itemList = snapshot.data ?? List();
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
      // return Center(child: Text('Awaiting result...'));
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              "Total: " + _getTotal(itemList).toString(),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
);
}
```

And this is the _getTotal function

```
int _getTotal(List<ItemList> itemLists) {
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < itemLists.length; i++) {
  var noOfItems = int.parse(itemLists[i].noOfItems);
  var unitPrice = int.parse(itemLists[i].unitPrice);
  multiple = noOfItems * unitPrice;
  total += multiple;
}
return total;
}
```